# Joomla 3 get configuration of other plugin onAfterInitialize()

Tags: plugins, joomla

Joomla 3 get configuration of other plugin onAfterInitialize()

I have two plugins authentication and system. I'd like make action onAfterInitialize event in system event using configuration defined in .xml file of authetication plugin. What's the right way to do it?

Do I need separate plugin for configuration and how do I call it?

Notice that onAfterInitialize event there are only system plugins loaded or I think it's so...

Thanks.

Comment: Joomla 3.5 has not yet been released. Are you sure you're not referring to `2.5` or `3.4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get params from one plugin in another with next code (its example for standard Authentication - Cookie plugin)

```
public function onAfterInitialise(){

    $plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('authentication', 'cookie');
    $params = new JRegistry($plugin->params);
    echo $params->get('cookie_lifetime','0');

}
```

Comment: This always returns 0.
I think that in phase (https://docs.joomla.org/Application_execution_order) onAfterInitialise() there are loaded only system plugins and I need to do something more, like load values from DB.

Comment: Code `print_r($plugin)` shows there are default values. I need use values set in configuration by user.